# How to get top 10 results and order by the most common one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I trying out a query where I'll get top 10 results from one table, then order it by the most common one or group by not sure how to build this though. So looking around for some help.

```
SELECT TOP 10 COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM [table]
WHERE COLUMN2 = 2
```

Then I get one result but I want it to be order by or grouped by the most common row in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try this one -

```
SELECT TOP 10 COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, cnt = COUNT(*) 
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE COLUMN2 = 2
    GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2 
) t
ORDER BY t.cnt DESC
```

Comment: Please refer this answer !

Comment: Lovely! Thank you very much. Tried it and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Although just to enlighten me, what is cnt and t? In the description. Just want to understand it better if you dont mind :) @Devart

Comment: `cnt` - column alias (is identical to: `COUNT(*) AS cnt`), `t` - sub-query alias (`t.cnt` - column from `t`)